# How to traverse a n-ary tree in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I've been trying to make this work for a while (I'm new to scheme).

```
(define atree '(10 (2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16))) (5 (7) (21)) (6)))

(define (children elem tree)
  (if (eqv? tree '())
      '()
      (if (number? (car tree))
          (if (eqv? elem (car tree))
              (getchilds (cdr tree))
              (children elem (cdr tree)))
          (if (eqv? elem (caar tree))
              (getchilds (cdar tree))
              (children elem (cadr tree))))))


(define (getchilds childNodes)
  (cond ((null? childNodes) '())
        (else (cons (caar childNodes)
                    (getchilds (cdr childNodes))))))
```

Ideally I should be able to return the children of a specific parent. And I've managed to make it work for numbers 10, 2, 5, 6 (ie `(children 10 tree)`. But I clearly did it  wrong since it won't work for any of the grandchild nodes.

My idea was to try to iterate through each element like a loop, but I don't think thats what I managed to accomplished. It's a n-ary tree that could have an arbitrary amount of nodes, I've tried googling and came up short.

Does anybody have a direction they could point me in? Ideally I just want to traverse every element of that list from left to right...

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious the mistake is that the list of children is a list of nodes while your procedure takes exactly one node.

You should split things up and make abstractions. How it's now your procedure does too much and you don't know if you are using `car` for a list element or the id of the node:

```
(define (node? tree)
  ...)
(node? '(1))         ; ==> #t
(node? '(1 (2) (3))) ; ==> #t
(node? '())          ; ==> #f
(node? '1)           ; ==> #f

(define (node-id tree)
  ...)
(node-id '(1 (2))) ; ==> 1

(define (node-children tree)
  ...)
(node-children '(1 (2) (3))) ; ==> ((2) (3))

(define (node-ids list-of-nodes)
  ...)
(node-list-ids '((2) (3))) ; ==> (2 3)

(define (find-node id tree)
  ...)
```

Now this one is where you are having problems. It takes one node as argument and not a list of nodes. To circumvent that you may want to make a helper that takes a list:

```
(define (find-node id tree)
  (let helper ((list-of-tree (list tree)))
    ...))

(find-node 1 '())          ; ==> #f 
(find-node 1 '(1 (2)))     ; ==> (1 (2)) 
(find-node 3 '(1 (2) (3))) ; ==> (3)
```

Or you can use higher order functions like [SRFI-1 has `any`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#Searching):

```
(define (find-node id tree)
  (let helper ((tree tree))
    (cond (<tree-is-not-a-node> #f)
          (<tree-has-same-id> tree)
          (else (any helper <list-of-children>)))))
```

Now you want the ids of the children of a certain node. When you have tested the abstractions it's really easy to make your procedure:

```
(define (find-child-ids id tree)
  (let ((tree (find-node id tree)))
    (if tree
        (node-list-ids (node-children tree))
        '()))) ; non existing node has no children

(find-node 1 '())      ; ==> () 
(find-node 1 '(1 (2))) ; ==> (2)
```

If I were to do this myself I might have used [SRFI-136 records](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-136/srfi-136.html) to model the tree.